# Trouble initialising NSMutableArray with NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsmutablearray, init

I'm having problem initialising an `NSMutableArray` called `_entryArray` with 2 `NSString` objects `@"00:00:00"`. I'm getting the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'

When I try to initialise it without any objects in it, I get no errors. What do I do?

Thank you very much

code:

```
@implementation MainViewController{

@private
int n;
NSMutableArray *_entryArray;
NSMutableArray *_timeSinceLastEntryArray;
NSMutableArray *_timeInterval;
NSMutableArray *_timeInBackup;
NSMutableArray *_timeOutBackup;
BOOL whichButton;


}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    n=0;
    _brain = [[Brain alloc] init];
    _entryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"00:00:00",@"00:00:00",nil];
    _timeSinceLastEntryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _timeInBackup = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSNumber *)0, nil];
    _timeOutBackup = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSNumber *)0, nil];
    _timeInterval = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}
```

Comment: What statement is giving you the exception you quote?  (Certainly not one of the statements you've listed above.)

Comment: `_timeInBackup = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSNumber *)0, nil];` should be `_timeInBackup = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@0, nil];` or in the old syntax `_timeInBackup = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];` same goes for `_timeOutBackup`.

Comment: (However, you might learn something if you NSLog the arrays you created.  _timeInBackup and _timeOutBackup do not contain the values you think they do.)

Comment: That's what I can't figure out. I don't get it if I initialise the _entryArray with just [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], but if I try to initialise it with objects the app wont even start

Comment: _entryArray is OK.  But NSLog everything, so you understand what you have.

Comment: but If I keep _timeInBackup and _timeOutBackup the way they are it still runs at least, I don't think they're the problem. I'll change them anyways, thanks :)

Comment: NSLog them, and see if they look like you expect.  NSLog is your friend.

Comment: (As it is, _entryArray is the only array with any contents.)

Comment: (And you still haven't shown us the statement that's giving the error.  It's identified by line number in the exception traceback, plus, if you enable the exception breakpoint, the debugger will stop right on it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two lines result in arrays with zero objects:

```
_timeInBackup = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSNumber *)0, nil];
_timeOutBackup = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSNumber *)0, nil];
```

You are not adding the number 0, you are adding the pointer 0. This is the same as `nil`. In other words, this code is really this:

```
_timeInBackup = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil, nil];
_timeOutBackup = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil, nil];
```

If your intent is to add the number 0, do this:

```
_timeInBackup = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];
_timeOutBackup = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];
```

Better yet, do this:

```
_timeInBackup = [@[ @0 ] mutableCopy];
_timeOutBackup = [@[ @0 ] mutableCopy];
```

You also have other empty arrays:`_timeSinceLastEntryArray` and `_timeInterval`. None of the code you have posted is actually causing the error. You need to provide more details to know for sure which array is really causing you the problem.

Comment: should be `[ @[ @0 ] mutableCopy]`

Comment: @xlc Thanks for noticing the typo. Fixed.